# Flexbox: How can child one have a width of its content and child 2 fills rest of width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a situation where I want to flexbox children to be side by side.
I want child one to have a width equal to the width of its content, and then child 2 to take up the remaining width of the parent.

I can't seem to make this work though

Here's what I have so far

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex-basis: content;
  background: red;
}

.flex-2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-child flex-1">
    Child 1, Child 1, Child 1
   </div>
   <div class="flex-child flex-2">
    Child 2, Child 2, Child 2
   <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `flex-grow` to the second child

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-1 {
  background: red;
}

.flex-2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-child flex-1">
    Child 1, Child 1, Child 1
   </div>
   <div class="flex-child flex-2">
    Child 2, Child 2, Child 2
   <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the flex of each children. Flex-1 should not grow but be auto width (flex: 0 1 auto) and flex-2 should be able to grow, shrink, and be auto width (flex: 1 1 auto)

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background: red;
}

.flex-2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-child flex-1">
    Child 1, Child 1, Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child flex-2">
    Child 2, Child 2, Child 2
    <div>
    </div>
```